# Chrome Extension - Getting "tab was closed" error on injecting a script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension which detects the type of file being opened and based on that injects a script on the page which does many other things. Here is the part of my code for the background.js which is injecting the script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
        console.log("Here: " + details.url + " Tab ID: " + details.tabId);
        if(toInject(details))
        {   
            console.log("PDF Detected: " + details.url);
            if(some-condition) 
            {
                //some code
            }
            else
            {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, { file: "contentscript.js", runAt: "document_start"}, function(result){
                    if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    {
                        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message + " Tab ID: " + details.tabId);
                    }
                });
            }
            return {
            responseHeaders: [{
              name: 'X-Content-Type-Options', 
              value: 'nosniff'
            }, 
                {
              name: 'X-Frame-Options', 
                /*
                    Deny rendering of the obtained data.
                    Cant use {cancel:true} as we still need the frame to be accessible.
                */
              value: 'deny'
            }]
          };
        }
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'],
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame']
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "ABCD",
    "description": "ABCD",
    "version": "1.2",

    "icons": {
        "16" :  "images/16.png",
        "32" :  "images/32.png",
        "48" :  "images/48.png",
        "128" :  "images/128.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "getFrameId", "aux.html", "chrome-extension:/*", "images/*.png", "images/*.gif", "style.css"]
}
```

The problem is that when injecting script the last error part runs and it shows the tab was closed and the script is not injected. If I press enter on the omnibox a several times the script is injected and things work fine. Here is a sample run of events:

[image: Sample output on console]

Sorry for my naive photo editing :P

There are a few more things we can deduce from this image:

1. The first thing being loaded in the tab with tab id 86 is something related to my google account. I have logged out and also turned off the prerender feature of chrome.
2. On pressing enter several times the tab was closed error goes but the script which maintains a `chrome.runtime` connection with the background.js gets disconnected.
3. And then finally things work fine.

I have been banging my head around this for days. No other question on SO addresses this problem. Nor anywhere else on the internet as well.

**EDIT:**

One more thing to note: The sample run shown in the image above is one such. There are many different behaviors. Sometimes 3 enters wouldn't make it work. Sometimes just one will. Is there something wrong because of the custom headers i am sending?

**UPDATE #1**

One must notice the headers I am returning in `OnHeadersReceived`. It's being done to stop chrome from rendering the document. But on doing that all the data of the file is dumped on the screen and I don't want that to appear. So i think I need `document_start` so that I can hide the dumped data before my content script does other things like putting a custom UI on the page.

**UPDATE #2**

Noticed one more thing. If I open a new tab, and then paste a url there and then press enter the following is the output of the background page on the console.

[image: Sample output number 2]

So I guess, the location of the window is updated at a later time by chrome. Am I right? Any workarounds?

Comment: 1) Try `runAt: "document_end"` 2) Try injecting the content script in `chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted` (set `doInject[details.tabId] = true` in `onHeadersReceived`, check it and delete the value in `onResponseStarted`)

Comment: Tried injecting in `chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted` using the approach you suggested. Still getting the same thing. Tried `document_end` as well didn't work. Also what I need is `document_start` see my update to understand more.

Comment: Why are you using my `executeScriptInFrame` library? It was fragile, that's why I ultimately decided to implement `redirectUrl` in Chrome and use it. This has been supported since Chrome 35, so there is no probably reason for using executeScriptInFrame over `redirectUrl`.

Comment: @RobW: What if i don't want to redirect? Plus, that script is required for a different objective, that script is not being used right now, it's just present there ill be using it later (may be not if you can explain more about what you are saying about redirectUrl).

Comment: @tapananand You've copied a snippet from PDF.js that is used to replace the page with a custom viewer. That's better done using `redirectUrl`. If you're actually trying to do something different, then please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RobW: Am i not allowed to copy some snippet from PDF.js? I don't have much idea about legality here.

Comment: @tapananand There's nothing wrong with copying snippets from PDF.js. What I do want to know is what you hope to achieve with that snippet, because -as I said- PDF.js uses that snippet to redirect to a custom viewer, and you just said that you don't want to redirect. If it is not relevant to the question, could you reduce the question to a minimal example that shows your problem? E.g. `toInject` is currently not defined, so I cannot run your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If i redirecturl, my url shown will change, which is what I dont want

Comment: You can assume toInject to be checking for a particular mime type, like pdf in case of PDF.js

Comment: @tapananand any further progress? Sir, have you resolved it??

Comment: None as far as using the same no redirect approach is concerned. Move this to chat if you have more to discuss

Answer (score 1):

`"The tab was closed"` error message is a bit misleading, because the tab obviously is not closed. In chrome sources the variable with the string is called `kRendererDestroyed`. So the error is because the corresponding renderer is being destroyed for some reason.

I was getting the error if the the page opened in tab redirected (thus one renderer destroyed, another one created for the same tab, but different url this time), in this case extension will got tab updates with statuses like:

- `loading` url: 'example.com', here tab is already returned to callbacks etc, but will get the error, if tried to inject script
- `loading` url: 'example.com/other_url'
- `title: 'some title'`
- `complete`

I managed to get around by injecting script only after receiving `status: 'complete'` (but probably injecting on `title` should also do)

Did not try with pdfs, but chrome probably will replace renderer for those too like with a redirect. So look more into page statuses and redirects/renderer replaces. Hope this helps anyone stumbling upon this question.

Comment: Hi, How did you do it? `status: 'complete'` what do you mean

Comment: @Melardev when attaching to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` (this is deprecated manifest v2 stuff, did not look into v3 yet) you get a few different events on different tab lifecycle stages with `changeInfo.status` mentioned above, if you try to interact with the tab too early - you get the error

Answer (score 0):

A simple setTimeout call to wait for the page to load worked for me.

Comment: Although this solution may be useful, it does not explain why the problem is occurring and does not seem to be the correct solution.